# js progress bar,html form error and pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I just want to make a form and wen users fill then click submit it should run a progress bar (which will run to 50%) and pop up error that will refer the user to "contact us" page......i.e the progress bar is supposed to pop up and run it shouldn't appear on the page except user click on the submit after filling the form.....here are my codes ... the progressive bar, the css and the html form

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
  var width = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 50) {
      clearInterval(id);
      $('#error').css("display", "block");
      $('#popupContact').css("display", "block");
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
      document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

#label {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}

#error {
  color: #F00;
  display: none;
}

#popupContact {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar">
    <div id="label">0%</div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button>

<div id="error">
  Could not connect; please transfer manually.
</div>

<!-- Popup div starts here -->
<div id="popupContact">
  <!-- contact us form -->
  <form action="#" method="post" id="form">
    <img src="images/3.png" id="close" onclick="div_hide()" />
    <h2>Transfer Details</h2>
    <hr/>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Reciever's information:</legend>
      Account Number:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="Account number" onkeyup="checkInput(this)" value="" id="name" placeholder="Account Number">
      <br> Account Name:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="Account Name" value="" id="name" placeholder="Account Name">
      <br>
      <br> Routing (ABA):
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="Routing (ABA)" onkeyup="checkInput(this)" id="name" value="" placeholder="Routing (ABA)">
      <br>
      <br> Bank Name:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="Bank Name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Bank Name">
      <br>
      <br> Account Type:
      <br>
      <select name="Account Type" placeholder="Account Type">
        <option>Fix Deposit</option>
        <option>Checking</option>
        <option>Savings</option>
        <option>Current</option>
      </select>
    </fieldset>
    <a id="submit" href="javascript: check_empty()" onclick="move()">Send</a>
    <p><span>Note :</span> All Form Is Required.</p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet is missing jQuery - you can include it using the dropdown on the left. Once you've done that it seems to work fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS progress bar, HTML form error and pop up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41947720/js-progress-bar-html-form-error-and-pop-up)

Comment: Looks like a deliberate copy+paste of your previous question? I suggest people who wish to answer reply to the older copy and not this one.